# How to make Qt5 QML Horizontal Listview enable mouse scroll?

Tags: listview, scroll, qml, mousewheel

I created a QML Horizoltal Listview but don't know how to enable horizontal scroll by mouse scroll. Please help. Thanks!

```
import Felgo 3.0
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

App {
    NavigationStack {
        Page {
            title: qsTr("Main Page")
            anchors.fill: parent
            Rectangle {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: "green"
                height: 66
                width: 333

                Flickable {
                    id: listController
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    //                        contentHeight: vert.contentHeight
                    //                        contentWidth: horizontalElement.width
                }
                ListView {
                    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                    clip: true
                    contentY: listController.contentX
                    spacing: 16
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    interactive: true
                    focus: true
                    delegate: Rectangle {
                        color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1);
                        width: 244
                        height: 66
                        radius: 14
                    }
                    model: 30

                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar{}
                    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{}
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
                    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar{
                        id: scroll
                        orientation: Qt.Vertical
                    }
//                    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{}
                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        onWheel: {
                            if (wheel.angleDelta.y > 0) scroll.increase()
                            else scroll.decrease()
                        }
                    }
```